# PayPal iOS-Sdk give Alert When i switch Sandbox Environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, paypal-sandbox

hey In Latest PayPal iOS Sdk Example It Run in "mock" fine But When I change Mode In "Sandbox" than i got issue "there was a problem communicating with paypal servers"..

[image: Error Alert]

Comment: This happens when you try to connect with your Paypal account ?

Comment: Yes in iOs-Sdk-Master Example It work fine in 'Mock' mode But while i change Sandbox mode it Gives This Alert @AnthonyRoani

Comment: Please can you show the code where you configure the Paypal environment object ? Also, to work with Sandbox mode you have to create an application in developer.paypal.com and then use the generated ID that is display in the appDelegate of your app. Did you make this ?

Comment: Yes bro I have done all the things and i am using that Example only which is provided by PayPal-iOS-SDK-master [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK)

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Please try to restart your app now. I notice that the paypal servers had real problems. Now it works so I think it should works for you too

Comment: Ok I think I should Reset all Data Of sandbox and Try Again I hope than it will Work

Comment: Are you still getting an error ?

Comment: No bro i think there is some technical issue from Paypal but now its working absolutely fine thank you @AnthonyRoani

Comment: Yes their servers had problems ! Cool :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello All I Faced This Problem Again And I Solved By my self
This Problem Occur because of internet provider restriction some are not support Paypal SSL request you Just Need to Change Internet Connection i prefer connect through wifi And Than Check It. I hope now Paypal will be run Smoothly